# Taking each item in a list and writing them on a text file

Tags: python, list

I have a list of numbers and need to put them all into a text file on their own line. I can't figure out how to call to each item and print them. I only know how to write strings into a text file.

Would I have to count each item and use the range function somehow? There has to be a better way. I'm pretty stuck with what to start with.

```
f = open("numbers.txt", "r")
numlist = []
for line in f:
  numlist.extend([n for n in map(float, line.split()) if n > 0])
print numlist
f.close()

g = open("output.txt", "w")
g.write(#writes each item in the list on its own line)
g.close()
```

Comment: Can you please include the code into the question instead of linking to a *screenshot*?

Comment: I tried to copy the code but my copy paste is buggy so it won't copy right. edit  nevermind, it formatted it for me

Comment: @Rob: Just format it manually...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or use string formatting

```
g = open('output.txt', 'w')
for num in numlist:
    g.write("%f\n" % num)
g.close()
```

Or you can change them to strings in your list comprehension:

```
numlist.extend([str(n) for n in map(float, line.split()) if n > 0])
```

Comment: There's one quote too much. That extend should better use a genexpr instead of a list comprehension, too.

Comment: Yeah, I edited the quote out. The list comprehension is from OPs code screenshot.

Comment: That doesn't mean that it can't be improved (rather to the contrary, it *should* be improved to help OP learn how it's done properly). You don't need to map to `float` first if what you want is to convert back to a string. A simple `numlist.extend(n for n in line.split() if float(n) > 0)` would be sufficient.

Comment: Ok. I understand for the most part, but the %f is new to me. Mind explaining it a bit?

Comment: %f is for floats. http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations

Answer (score 2):

Since it seems to be homework I'm just going to give some pointing:

- You can handle multiple files with one `with` statement, take a look at: [Python: open multiple files using “with open”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4617034/1132524): *(I'll write this one for you)*

  ```
  with open('numbers.txt') as input_file, open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file:
  ```
- Loop line by line of the `input_file`.
- [`strip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) and [`split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the line and loop on it.
- Check your contintion:

  ```
  if float(num) > 0:
  ```
- And if pass with your `num + '\n'`.

Comment: This is very helpful. We haven't learned about opening both files like that. But it makes it a lot easier. Thank you!!