# open multiple sets of multiple files in different modes using with

Tags: python, file-io, python-3.x

This question is related to this question: [How can I open multiple files using "with open" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617034/python-open-multiple-files-using-with-open)

I could have three sets of files: files1, files2 and file3

I can open files1 and files2 for reading and file3 for writing by doing this:

```
with fileinput.input(files=files1) as f1, fileinput.input(files=files2) as f2, open(file3,'w') as f3:
```

In Python 3 (not Python 2), how could I achieve this, if I had hundreds of sets of files?

I had a look at the contextlib module, but I'm not sure, how I would do this in the most Pythonic way.

http://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `contextlib.ExitStack` class you linked to is exactly what you want:

```
with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
    inputs = [stack.enter_context(fileinput.input(files=filename))
              for filename in input_filenames]
    outputs = [stack.enter_context(open(filename, "w"))
               for filename in output_filenames]

    # do stuff with inputs and outputs here
```

This structure will guarantee that all open files will be closed if there is an exception raised at any point, including during the opening of the later files.

Comment: Thanks @Blckknght. I wasn't 100% sure this was the right approach. The contextlib module is great. Now I can avoid nested with statements in a beautiful way.