# Reading and writing to file

Tags: python, regex, file

```
with open('C:\Users\ehwe\Desktop\INPUT_DS_FILE.txt') as old, open('C:\Users\ehwe\Desktop\OUTPUT_DS_FILE.txt', 'w') as new:
        for line in old:
            if re.search('trim\(\w+\)',line) == None:
                new.write(line)
            else:
                new_line = re.sub(r"trim\((\w+)\)", r"TRIM (TRIM (CHR (09) FROM \1))", line)
                new.write (new_line)
```

This chunk of code reads line from old file and writes it to a new one. It makes certain modifications according to a pattern.

Problem is - I am not able to run the code - the compiler keeps saying **SyntaxError: invalid syntax**  and highlights the **comma** in the very first line.

Little help please?

P.S.

the code below works fine (in case someone points out that slashes might go wrong)

```
with open('C:\Users\ehwe\Desktop\INPUT_DS_FILE.txt') as old:
    for line in old:
        if re.search('trim\(\w+\)',line) != None:
            print 'Y'
```

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: The slashses ARE a problem. It's possible the interpreter get's it wrong about the position of the error. Try fixing the slases, and see if the error changes.

Comment: This syntax is only available from 2.7

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617034/python-open-multiple-files-using-with-open

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the backslashes in your open statement

```
with open('C:\\Users\\ehwe\\Desktop\\INPUT_DS_FILE.txt') as old, open('C:\\Users\\ehwe\\Desktop\\OUTPUT_DS_FILE.txt', 'w') as new:
...
```

Optionally, you can always use forward slashes, and avoid the backslash issue (fyi -- windows fully understands and accepts forward slashes), eg:

```
with open('C:/Users/ehwe/Desktop/INPUT_DS_FILE.txt') as old, open('C:/Users/ehwe/Desktop/OUTPUT_DS_FILE.txt', 'w') as new:
...
```

Comment: Or just use forward slashes.

Comment: I was adding this exact clarification (just as you posted)

Comment: both approaches didnt help :(

Answer (score 0):

Or use Python Raw strings:

```
with open(r'C:\Users\ehwe\Desktop\INPUT_DS_FILE.txt') as old, open(r'C:\Users\ehwe\Desktop\OUTPUT_DS_FILE.txt', 'w') as new:
```