# Python read and write in same function

Tags: python-2.7, csv

My code is currently taking in a csv file and outputting to text file. The piece of code I have below and am having trouble with is from the csv I am searching for a keyword like issues and every row that has that word I want to output that to a text file. Currently, I have it printing to a JSON file but its all on one line like this
"something,something1,something2,something3,something4,something5,something6,something7\r\n""something,something1,something2,something3,something4,something5,something6,something7\r\n"

But i want it to print out like this:

"something,something1,something2,something3,something4,something5,something6,something7"
"something,something1,something2,something3,something4,something5,something6,something7"

Here is the code I have so far:

```
def search(self, filename):
        with open(filename, 'rb') as searchfile, open("weekly_test.txt", 'w') as text_file:
            for line in searchfile:
                if 'PBI 43125' in line:
                    #print (line)
                    json.dump(line, text_file, sort_keys=True, indent = 4)
```

So again I just need a little guidance on how to get my json file to be formatted the way I want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I open multiple files using "with open" in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617034/how-can-i-open-multiple-files-using-with-open-in-python)

Comment: that is not what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `print line` with `print >>file, line`

```
def search(self, filename):
    with open('test.csv', 'r') as searchfile, open('weekly_test.txt', 'w') as search_results_file:
        for line in searchfile:
            if 'issue' in line:
                print >>search_results_file, line

    # At this point, both the files will be closed automatically
```

Comment: @Turtle23 No problem! If you are satisfied with the answer, please upvote and accept it to close the question.