# How can I trim down this code?

Tags: python

I have two text files "usernames.txt" and "passwords.txt" and I want to have them print out in a specific order, I have a snippet of code that does exactly what I need but I feel like It can be shortened.

```
with open('passwords.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for password in line.split():
            with open('usernames.txt','r') as f:
                for line in f:
                    for username in line.split():
                        print username +":"+ password
```

This works perfect for me what I feel like I can make it even shorter!

current output is this:

```
username1:password
username1:password1
username1:password2
username2:password
username2:password1
username2:password2
```

Comment: Show the input files used to generate that sample output.

Comment: Questions about improving or maintaining code should be posted over at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry about making it shorter, make it more readable by removing nesting.

1. [Open both files in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4617069/1083707)
2. Extract the data with a nested [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
3. Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get your combinations

Something like this

```
    import itertools

    with open('passwords.txt', 'r') as pf, open('usernames.txt', 'r') as uf:
        passwords = [pwd for line in pf for pwd in line.split()]
        usernames = [uname for line in uf for uname in line.split()]

    for username, password in itertools.product(usernames, passwords):
        print("{}: {}".format(username, password)
```

Comment: Use `itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(operator.methodcaller("split"), pf))` and so as for `uf`. Then use it for the `itertools.product` **inside** the with statement. Will be WAY more efficient, and consume less memory.

Answer (score -1):

Not much shorter (5 vs 7 lines) but at least a bit more readable, if I say so myself:

```
passwords = open('passwords.txt').readlines()
usernames = open('usernames.txt').readlines()

for p in passwords:
    for u in usernames:
        print '%s:%s' % (u.strip(), p.strip())
```

**Edit**

This answer assumes your `passwords.txt` and `usernames.txt` have one entry per line. Not a single line with multiple entries.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. The OP uses `split()` (which returns an list) and not `.strip()` (which returns a string).

Comment: The output of my version is the same as OP's, though. Without examples of his source files I can only make assumptions. My assumption was that the files would contain one entry per line.

Comment: I realize you're quite a new member so please have a look at [How to answer (help center)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). I think the general guideline is that if you don't know why/what the OP is doing then you should ask for clarification (comments) and **not** make assumptions.