# How to convert large json file to CSV using pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I am trying to convert yelp challenge dataset from json to csv format using pandas. My session crashed with memory error. like Not enough memory. I am using google colab high RAM. My code works for other files except yelp_academic_dataset_review.json file. Following is my code sample.  Can anyone suggest me any solution? Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('/content/drive/MyDrive/Data/yelp_academic_dataset_review.json', lines=True)

df.to_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Data/yelp_review.csv', index = None)
```

Comment: If the incoming file is one json object per line a [solution like in the top answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42169287/python-performance-tuning-json-to-csv-big-file) would be appropriate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read a large csv file with pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-do-i-read-a-large-csv-file-with-pandas) The solution to use `chunksize` should apply to JSON as well.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get that. It's one file named yelp_academic_dataset_review.json @JNevill