# Unable to get text file output in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, output

I have taken input from Numbers.txt file and want to write output in out.txt file,
can anyone guide what is going wrong.

```
import num2word_EN as s
text = open("C:\\Users\\eanaaks\\Desktop\\Python Practice Program\\Numbers.txt","r")
outfile = open("C:\\Users\\eanaaks\\Desktop\\Python Practice Program\\out.txt", "w")
for line in text:
    line = line.rstrip()
    num = int(line)
    print line
    x = s.to_card(num)
    print (x)
outfile.write("%s\n"%(line));
outfile.close()
text.close()
```

Comment: How does your file look like?

Comment: You need to indent `out_file.write()` otherwise you'll only write the last line

Comment: You didn't do `text.close()`, have a look at the example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617034/how-can-i-open-multiple-files-using-with-open-in-python which makes it easier to code bug free. Also I wouldn't  import something within a for loop.

Comment: BTW, you should normally put `import` statements at the top of the script, not buried somewhere in the middle, and especially not inside a loop. It doesn't really matter that your  `import` is in the loop because Python is smart enough to only import the module once, but it still looks messy.

Comment: Also, `x="";` is useless. And there's no need to terminate Python statements with a semicolon.

Comment: also, don't write files into python installation !!!

Comment: Still struggling with same no output can anyone frame the code.

Comment: please post your fixed code, since you followed advice in comments. and do you have permissions to write in `c:/python27` ? it's a bad idea whatever.

Comment: You have modified the code according to some suggestions but not all. The most important one "Indent the outfile.write("%s\n"%(line));" is not done. Others like the end semicolon is also not done. Please modify your code making all changes suggested by people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an improved version of your code:

```
import num2word_EN as s

input_file = 'C:\Users\eanaaks\Desktop\Python Practice Program\Numbers.txt'
output_file = 'C:\Users\eanaaks\Desktop\Python Practice Program\out.txt'

with open(input_file, 'r') as fin 
    with open(output_file, 'w') as fout:
        for line in fin:
            num = int(line)
            print(line)
            x = s.to_card(num)
            print(x)
            # What's the data type of x? int? string?
            # This will write the original data and the processed data separated by tab.
            fout.write('%s\t%s\n' % (line.rstrip(), x));
```

Comment: Hi, I'm a beginner just started to learn. Appreciate you provided the improved code but output is not processed it is the same as input provided, i hope we have to append the processed part and add into fout.

Comment: Yes, your code is basically taking a line from input file, sending the number to card and copying the line to output file. Is `x` your processed data?

Comment: Yes x is processed data.

Comment: martijnn2008 even if open defaults to 'r' I think it's clearer if it's specified, specially if the OP is starting to code. Also I would use two lines even if there's extra indentation for clarity.

Comment: Then in the output file you want only the processed data, or both? If it's both you should specify how they are put together: concatenated, different lines?

Comment: both together concatenated.

Comment: Done using tabs. Replace `\t` by ' ' (space) or ',' (comma) if you want different separators.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  :)

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki, ok I guess that is a matter of taste I guess.