# python 2.7 search and replace multiple lines in a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python function that is supposed to receive:

- A file path
- A list of tuples with old value to find and new value to replace it.

The script is supposed **to produce the same file modified with the tuple values (old to new)**. This is what I have tried so far:

```
def inplace_change(new_filename, old_string_new):
        for old_new in old_string_new:
            with open(new_filename, "rt") as fin:
                with open(new_filename, "wt") as fout:
                    for line in fin:
                        fout.write(line.replace(old_new[0], old_new[1]))
```

I generally pass them alist of tuples like this:

```
[('PidFile=/path/xxx.pid',
        'PidFile=/path/xxx.' + container_name + '.pid'),
       ('LogFile=/xx/log/nc_zabbix_agentd.log',
        'LogFile=/xx/log/yyyy.' + container_name + '.log')
    ...]
```

Then a normal path where the file is.

I manage to replace only a tuple (single old string with new string) very easily, but when I have the list I can not get the logic to get this done. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at `re.sub`? Compile a pattern programmatically to do it.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: no error. get a blank file at this end with this version of the code.

Comment: I have not looked into `re.sub`. I will check it out, but do not know the module in general.

Comment: You can open multiple files with a single with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617034/how-can-i-open-multiple-files-using-with-open-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
import os

def replace_in_file(fn, replaces):
    with open(fn, 'r') as f1, open(fn+'.new', 'w') as f2:
        for line in f1.readlines():
            for a, b in replaces:
                line = line.replace(a, b)
            f2.write(line)
    os.rename(fn+'.new', fn)

replace_in_file('foo.txt', (('foo', 'bar'), ('hey', 'ho')))
```

Answer (score 2):

**The culprit**:

```
for old_new in old_string_new:
```

**Should have been**:

```
for old_val, new_val in old_string_new:
```

**Changing this line**:

```
fout.write(line.replace(old_new[0], old_new[1]))
```

**to this**:

```
fout.write(line.replace(old_val, new_val))
```

I have minimized your problem, the following should be very easy to understand:

```
old_string_new  = [ ('old1', 'new1'), ('old2', 'new2'), ('old3', 'new3')]

for old_val, new_val in old_string_new: 
    print(old_val, new_val)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
old1 new1
old2 new2
old3 new3
```

**EDIT**:

A detailed answer with tested code, Suppose we have a file as follow:

list.txt:

```
old1 hello there
okay old2 you will be replaced
haha bye bye old3
```

**With the Code**:

```
import fileinput as fp

def inplace_change(filename, old_string_new):
    for old_val, new_val in old_string_new:
        with fp.FileInput(filename, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
            for line in file:
                print(line.replace(old_val, new_val), end='')


old_string_new  = [('old1', 'new1'), ('old2', 'new2'), ('old3', 'new3')]
inplace_change('list.txt', old_string_new)
```

**OUTPUT (list.txt)**:

```
new1 hello there
okay new2 you will be replaced
haha bye bye new3
```

Comment: It does not change the final output. it still does not work. same result; a blank file.

Comment: I highly doubt, post the code that is using this approach in your question.

Comment: @wti I am adding a detailed answer while I do so, know that you need `a+` not `wt`

Comment: @wti Kindly check the edited version of the answer.

Comment: hi @DirtyBit, thanks for your answer, it seems with a bit of work could be the right answer, but the answer from geckos, works out of the box and came first. I get this error with your anser: `print(line.replace(old_val, new_val), end='')
SyntaxError: invalid syntax` seems it could be solved easily in any case, but I already have a working answer.

Comment: @wti Ah, that is because youre using Python 2.x. No worries, glad it helped! :)