# How to read a CSV and adapt + write every row to another CSV?

Tags: python, csv

I tried this but it just writes "lagerungskissen kleinkind,44" several times instead of transferring every row.

```
keyword = []
rank = []
rank = list(map(int, rank)) 
data = []
with open("keywords.csv", "r") as file:  
    for line in file:
        data = line.strip().replace('"', '').split(",")
        keyword = data[0]
        rank = data[3]

    import csv
    with open("mynew.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
        thewriter = csv.writer(f)
        thewriter.writerow(["Keyword", "Rank"])
        for row in keyword:
            thewriter.writerow([keyword, rank])
```

It should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qd3E2.png)

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is writing the same line in your output CSV because the final block is

```py
for row in keyword:
    thewriter.writerow([keyword, rank])
```

Note that the `keyword` variable doesn't change in the loop, but the `row` does. You're writing that same `[keyword, rank]` line `len(keyword)` times.

I would use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) package to do the reading and the writing for this. Something like

```py
import csv

input_file = '../keywords.csv'
output_file = '../mynew.csv'

# open the files
fIn = open(input_file, 'r', newline='')
fOut = open(output_file, 'w')
csvIn = csv.reader(fIn, quotechar='"')  # check the keyword args in the docs!
csvOut = csv.writer(fOut)

# write a header, then write each row one at a time
csvOut.writerow(['Keyword', 'Rank'])
for row in csvIn:
    keyword = row[0]
    rank = row[3]
    csvOut.writerow([keyword, rank])

# and close the files
fOut.close()
fIn.close()
```

As as side note, you could write the above using the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) context manager (e.g. `with open(...) as file:`). The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617034/how-can-i-open-multiple-files-using-with-open-in-python) shows how to do it with multiple files (in this case `fIn` and `fOut`).