# how to use " with open " to compare the different of two file in python

Tags: python

I am new to Python. I want to compare two files (1.txt and 2.txt).

Content of 1.txt:

```
a
b
c
```

Content of 2.txt:

```
a
b
c
d
```

the program code:

```
with open("1.txt") as f1:
    with open("2.txt") as f2:
        for line in f2.readlines():
            if line not in f1.readlines():
                print(line)
```

when I run the code, the output is:

```
b

c

d
```

In my opinion, it should only output the "d", which the letter exits in 2.txt, not in the 1.txt. 
So, anyone can tell why the output like in the picture?

Then I debug the program, and watches the two variables: "f1.readlines()" and "f2.readlines()" in the right corner.

I use the "Step Over" to the **line 3**, in the watches window, "f1.readlines()" and f2.readlines()"
is still null, I can't figure it.

[image]

When i want to use "Step Over" to the line 4,the window becomes this:
[image]

all the avriables are not available

So,my question is :

1 why my code can't work?

2 what is the right code to compare the "1.txt" and "2.txt"?

Thanks!

Comment: It's probably an issue caused by re-evaluating the contents of `f1` for every line in `f2`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I open multiple files using "with open" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617034/how-can-i-open-multiple-files-using-with-open-in-python)

Comment: @pault - There isn't anything wrong with how the op is opening the files, re-reading `f1` every iteration is likely to be an issue though

Comment: I can't see the images [blocked] but there's definitely something wrong with OP's indentation

Comment: fixed indentation, it was correct in the (gently weeps) screenshots of the IDE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Once you've read all the lines in a file, there are no more lines in the file to read, pretty much by definition.

   So, after your first call to `f1.readlines()`, every subsequent call will return an empty list.

   You'll either need to `seek` back to the beginning, or save the result of `readlines()` (assuming both files will always fit in memory)
2. the right code is likely to use [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html)

Answer (score 1):

for educational purposes, you could change your code to do this instead:

```
with open("2.txt") as f2:
    for line in f2.readlines():
        with open("1.txt") as f1:
            if line not in f1.readlines():
                print(line)
```

and it should do the right thing, for reasons explained by @Useless (who apparently isn't :)

note that you shouldn't normally do this, it'll take [O(JK)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) operations where J and K are the number of lines in each file, while algorithms in `difflib` will be much more efficient.  try your version on files with a 10k lines and it'll probably take a few minutes, while `difflib` should take a few milliseconds.