# I have a folder in which multiple .txt files are there . i want to write in all the files at the same time . please help.the code should be in python

Tags: python-3.x

import os 
directory = os.listdir("E:\append_some_line_to_the_start_of_a_file")
for file in directory:
    print(file)

afer this I want to write in all the files in the same time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617034/how-can-i-open-multiple-files-using-with-open-in-python This thread seems to be what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You should use ExitStack for this:

```
from contextlib import ExitStack
import os

dir = 'E:\append_some_line_to_the_start_of_a_file'
with ExitStack() as stack:
    files = [stack.enter_context(open(os.path.join(dir,fname), 'w')) for fname in os.listdir('./dir')]
    for file in files:
        file.write('test')
```