# How to open multiple files in loop, in python

Tags: python

I'm new to python.
I'm want to open multiple files in Python. I'm can open each of them with `open()` function.
I'm not sure about formatting.

```
with open("/test/filename.css", "r") as f:
     s = f.readlines()
     print(s)
```

I'm can open one file, but I'm not sure how to open multiple files.
This is the code that I have. In `live_filename()` function have many files.

```
inputfiles = live_filename()
    for live in inputfiles:
        with open("/test/............. .css, "r") as f:
```

I don't know how to put code formatting in space. and I think the `live` variable is a tuple can't concatenate str. what should i do?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a sample input by `print`ing the return value of `live_filename()`.

Comment: @Selcuk what should i do?

Comment: @lalin Edit your question to show us the result of `print(inputfiles)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I open multiple files using "with open" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617034/how-can-i-open-multiple-files-using-with-open-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open each just as you did for one, and then *append* them to a list:

```py
import os

folderpath = r"D:\my_data" # make sure to put the 'r' in front
filepaths  = [os.path.join(folderpath, name) for name in os.listdir(folderpath)]
all_files = []

for path in filepaths:
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        file = f.readlines()
        all_files.append(file)
```

Now, `all_files[0]` holds the *first* file loaded, `all_files[1]` the *second*, and so on.

---

**UPDATE**: for all files in the same folder: first, get the folder path (on Windows, [like this](https://puu.sh/ElrpX/d9c5d91c8d.png)). Suppose it's `"D:\my_data"`. Then, you can get all the *filepaths* of the files as in the script above.

Comment: I got it. I make it in function live_filename(). Do I have to do it again?

Comment: @lalin Just make sure `filepaths` contains all paths of files you plan to load - you can check via `print(filepaths)`. If so, no need to repeat.

Comment: I got it. I will try this. :)

Comment: I try this.but error show ==> expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple

Comment: @lalin If you didn't change your `live_filename()` and it has the same output, then that is the problem. Just don't use it - instead follow my answer instructions step-by-step.

Comment: @ Okay. I will try again. :)

Comment: I can do it. Thank you very much :)))))

Comment: @lalin Congrats. Consider [accepting](https://puu.sh/ElDqq/cd2cee0310.png) the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
folder = "..." # Absolute path to folder in which the files reside
files_to_read = [("filename.css","FileName"),( "filename2.css","Filename2")]
for (file, _) in files_to_read:
    filepath = os.path.join(folder, file)
    with open(filepath, "r") as f:
        s = f.readlines()
        print(s)
```

Comment: I got it, but if I have 100 files. what should i do?

Comment: @lalin Are all these files in the _same folder_?

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Yes in the same folder.

Comment: @lalin Do you want it to be processed in parallel? You are receiving file paths from a function right? Can you show a sample output of `live_filename()`

Comment: @MjZac Yes I receiving file paths from a function.
output is :
('home', 'Home')
('fun', 'Fun')

Comment: Then it's just `for (file, _) in live_filename():`