# Python: Take CSV tables and find the 4 highest values and their location

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-processing

I have a folder of 310 .csv files. Here is a sample of what the contents look like [image: csv table example]
I need to create a program that goes through all the files, lists the file name, then lists the top 4 values from the table and the x-value associated with it. Ideally this would all be saved to a text doc but as long as it prints in a readable format that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

So, what is stopping you? [Loop through the files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58108964/how-to-open-multiple-files-in-loop-in-python), use  [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to import each csv file and [merge/join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) them all into one `DataFrame`. Use [slicing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#slicing-ranges) to select the 4 top rows, and you can always print/visualize anything directly in a Jupyter Notebook. Exporting can be done using [`df.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html?highlight=to_csv#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv) or [any other method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html) and if you need a short introduction to `pandas`, look [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html).

*Keep in mind that it is always a good idea, to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Especially for a complicated merge operation between many DataFrames, this could help you a lot. However, there is no way around [some research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).*