# Python - read from multiple big files in paralell and yield them individually

Tags: python, file-io, bigdata

I have multiple big files and need to yield them round-robin style line by line. Something like this pseudo code:

```
    def get(self):
        with open(file_list, "r") as files:
            for file in files:
                yield file.readline()
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Found a possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617034/how-can-i-open-multiple-files-using-with-open-in-python?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `itertools` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) has several recipes, among them a very neat round-robin recipe. I would also use [`ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) to work with multiple file context-managers:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice
from contextlib import ExitStack

# https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    num_active = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while num_active:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            # Remove the iterator we just exhausted from the cycle.
            num_active -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, num_active))

...

def get(self):
    with open(files_list) as fl:
        filenames = [x.strip() for x in fl]
    with ExitStack() as stack:
        files = [stack.enter_context(open(fname)) for fname in filenames]
        yield from roundrobin(*files)
```

Although, perhaps the best design is to use inversion of control, and provide the sequence of file-objects as an argument to `.get`, so the calling code should take care of using an exit-stack:

```
class Foo:
    ...
    def get(self, files):
        yield from roundrobin(*files)

# calling code:
foo = Foo() # or however it is initialized

with open(files_list) as fl:
    filenames = [x.strip() for x in fl]
with ExitStack() as stack:
    files = [stack.enter_context(open(fname)) for fname in filenames]
    for line in foo.get(files):
        do_something_with_line(line)
```

Comment: The `file_list` is meant to be a python list of file name strings.

Comment: `open` doesn't accept a list as input though, does it? it takes `str`, `bytes`, `os.path`-like object. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, you are right. My code however is meant to be only pseudocode. I assumed the hypothetical existence of such an 'open' command.

Answer (score 0):

This would be tricky (or require some additional libraries) to do using a context manager, but it shouldn't be very difficult without. `open()` takes the name of a single file, so assuming `file_list` is a list of strings naming the input files, this should work:

```
def get(files_list):
  file_handles = [open(f, 'r') for f in files_list]
  while file_handles:
    for fd in file_handles:
      line = fd.readline()
      if line:
        yield line
      else:
        file_handles.remove(fd)
```

I'm assuming you want to keep going until every line is read from every file, with shorter files dropping off as they hit EOF.