# Why am I getting "[Errno 13] Permission denied:" when making consecutive open and write calls?

Tags: python, json, file-permissions, codec, file-writing

**Update**

It's throwing the error with a direct call now, and in the relations docs. I got rid of `write_el()` altogether and just do this:

```
...
if el["doc_type"] == "node":
    with codecs.open((fo_pre+"_nodes.json"), mode) as fo:
        fo.write(json.dumps(el, indent=2)+"\n")
...
```

Also, it should be noted that the XML document (OSM) has all the node elements first, followed by the way elements, then the relation elements.

**Original post**

I'm writing to multiple JSON files from within Python `xml.etree.ElemenTree.iterparse`, using `codecs.open` and `json.dumps`. I call a separate function to write to the file.

This works for some of the elements/documents, but not all. It writes only so many then stops with `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: <file name>`. The last call to the file write method returns 207, but so do many of the previous calls. And, the next element looks normal:

```
<!--Last element written to JSON file.-->
  <node id="7898832843" lat="48.7888301" lon="-122.5067978" version="1" timestamp="2020-09-11T22:37:30Z" changeset="90779671" uid="10612244" user="mapstuffs"/>

<!--Next element, not written to JSON file.-->
  <node id="7898832844" lat="48.7888177" lon="-122.5058429" version="1" timestamp="2020-09-11T22:37:30Z" changeset="90779671" uid="10612244" user="mapstuffs"/>
```

Plus, it throws the error at a different element each time I try. And, it sometimes doesn't throw the error.

Stripped down Python:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import codecs
import json

def write_el(el, file_out, mode = "a"):
    with codecs.open(file_out, mode) as fo:
        fo.write(json.dumps(el, indent=2)+"\n")
    return

def process_map(file_in, fo_pre, mode = "a"):
    
    for _, element in ET.iterparse(file_in):
        # shape_element() formats XML elements into JSON-compatible Python
        # dictionaries and lists.
        el = shape_element(element)
        if el:
            if el["doc_type"] == "node":
# Calling open/write directly works.
#                 with codecs.open(fo_pre+"_nodes.json", mode) as fo:
#                     fo.write(json.dumps(el, indent=2)+"\n")
# But, calling write_el for this doc_type throws permission error
# halfway through the document. The element following the last written looks
# just fine.
                write_el(el=el, file_out=fo_pre+"_nodes.json", mode=mode)
# Calling write_el works fine for the other doc_types, if error not thrown
# from previous block first.
            elif el["doc_type"] == "way":
                write_el(el=el, file_out=fo_pre+"_ways.json", mode=mode)
            elif el["doc_type"] == "relation":
                write_el(el=el, file_out=(fo_pre+"_relations.json"),
                         mode=mode, write=write, pretty=pretty)
                
def test():
    process_map(file_in=filename, fo_pre="test_bham", write=True)

    return

test()
```

Returns

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test_bham_nodes.json'
```

Comment: Because you don't have the permission to access that file. You should check the permissions of the file and/or directory on the OS level.

Comment: The problem is that I do have permissions, since I am able to create it and write to it up until a certain point, within the same runtime of the same script.

Comment: Could my permissions change?

Comment: Not sure, but I think Windows might be reporting "permission denied" for different kind of failures, for example, you tried to open the same file twice, but did not close it. Maybe `file_in` and `file_out` are the same? But this is just a guess, it could be anything.

Comment: I like that you're thinking about this, thanks. I'm using ```with open```, so it should handle its closing at the end of the block. And, ```file_in`` is "bellingham_map.osm", so it's not the same as ```file_out```. I think you're right about the error being used for a range of problems. I haven't found an example that fits this one, though.

Comment: Which operating system are you running?

Comment: ...that said, if you just hold a single file descriptor open and don't re-open the file, there aren't further permission checks. Reopening something over-and-over is really slow, anyhow.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Okay -- that introduces a bunch of potential interestingness (Windows is a lot more restrictive than UNIX-y platforms about concurrent file access).

Comment: _Why_ are you reopening the file every time you want to write a single element? It would be much, _much_ faster and more reliable to just open it once before writing anything, and closing it only when completely done.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's what I was doing before when I wrote to a single file, but I want to write to N number of files without parsing through the XML doc N number of times.

Comment: Do you have a virus scanner that’s making your file in use every time you close it as it scans the new file?

Comment: @MarkTolonen, I do have Norton, and I'm doing this in Jupyter Notebook, which I think also accesses it to update its directory. I was just thinking Jupyter might be trying to access the file at the same time. Maybe Norton is too.

Comment: It’s probably Norton. Jupyter wouldn’t have to open it just to update a directory

Comment: What I'm finding is that restarting the kernel seems to do the trick, at least with a direct call. I don't know why, but I will take it. Now I'll try calling open/write from within another function after restarting the kernel.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, it is a lot slower. Can I nest ```with open()``` blocks?

Comment: Nesting ```with open()``` has done it. Thanks, @CharlesDuffy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some commentors, I've found that nesting `with open()` outside of `iterparse()` does the trick.

My antivirus program was likely the culprit, accessing the file each time it was closed, which occasionally caused an access conflict on the next file open operation.

I didn't like opening and closing the file for each element because of the operation cost, and I originally had parsed the XML from within the file open when I was writing to a single file. But, when I decided to write to multiple files, I didn't want to parse the XML over again for each JSON file I wanted to write from it.

Seems like a no-brainer now, but nesting file opens works and saves compute. It might build up the indents if you want to write a lot of files, but c'est la vie.

```
def process_map(file_in, fo_pre, mode = "a"):
    
    with codecs.open(fo_pre+"_nodes.json", mode) as nd_fo, \
    codecs.open(fo_pre+"_ways.json", mode) as wy_fo, \
    codecs.open(fo_pre+"_relations.json", mode) as rl_fo:

        for _, element in ET.iterparse(file_in):
                el = shape_element(element)
                if el:
                    if el["doc_type"] == "node":
                        write_el(el=el, file_out=fo_pre+"_nodes.json",
                                 mode=mode)
                    elif el["doc_type"] == "way":
                        write_el(el=el, file_out=fo_pre+"_ways.json",
                                 mode=mode)
                    elif el["doc_type"] == "relation":
                        write_el(el=el, file_out=fo_pre+"_relations.json",
                                 mode=mode)

    return
```

Comment: You don't need to indent, you can open several items with one `with`. See [How can I open multiple files using `with open` in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617034/how-can-i-open-multiple-files-using-with-open-in-python)