# Clean way to open/close an optional file in python?

Tags: python, file-handling

My code:

```
fh = None
if args.optional_input_file_path is not None:
    fh = open(args.optional_input_file_path)

my_function(foo, bar, fh)

if args.optional_input_file_path is not None:
    fh.close()
```

I don't like how I need to write `if args.optional_input_file is not None:` twice.

Moving the conditional logic inside `my_function` also isn't ideal because I'm intentionally passing in `IO` objects to the function instead of file paths to make it easier to test.

Is there a cleaner way to achieve the same thing?

**I want to be able to write `my_function(foo, bar, fh)` exactly once, and have `fh` be either an `IO` object or `None`, depending on the value of `args.optional_input_file_path`.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I open multiple files using "with open" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617034/how-can-i-open-multiple-files-using-with-open-in-python)

Comment: Do you know about the with clause

Comment: You could write `if fh is not None` instead, which is shorter

Comment: why cant just put `open, my_function, close` inside one if condition

Comment: @JonSG  you can't `with` open a `None` file path

Comment: @BlueRobin I don't think that's the same question? I'm asking how to make `with open(filepath) as f` work when `filepath` could be `None`.

Comment: You check guard against reading a bad file path once and the with causes does the close for you. That is how you clean it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
my_function(foo, bar, open(args.file_path) if args.file_path else None)
```

As there is no reference to file open, it will auto close in the next GC

Comment: I don't think this is any cleaner because there's also an `else: my_function(foo, bar, None)` needed. I want to be able to write `my_function(foo, bar, fh)` exactly once, and have `fh` be either an `IO` object or `None`, depending on the value of `args.optional_input_file_path`

Comment: I'm not sure if relying on GC like that is the best but this certainly seems like the simplest approach -- thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use a custom [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager) that propagates `None` but otherwise behaves like [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

```
import contextlib


@contextlib.contextmanager
def open_not_none(file, *args, **kwargs):
    if file is not None:
        with open(file, *args, **kwargs) as f:
            yield f
    else:
        yield None
```

which can be used as

```
with open_not_none(args.optional_input_file_path, "r") as fh:
    my_function(foo, bar, fh)
```

This lets you keep all the benefits of opening the file in a [with statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) while avoiding duplicating the call to `my_function` for the `None` and not-`None` cases. You may also richly type hint it with [`typing.overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) if you so choose.

---

**edit:** after seeing [Frank Yellin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75845267/11082165) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75845267/11082165), I realized that this could be implemented more simply using [`contextlib.nullcontext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nullcontext) as

```
def open_not_none(file, *args, **kwargs):
    if file is None:
        return contextlib.nullcontext()
    return open(file, *args, **kwargs)
```

The usage is exactly the same.

The original approach works by creating and activating a new a context manager that either wraps the `open`-context-manager or does nothing. In this second approach, we get rid of that extra layer of context-manager indirection, and substitute with either returning the `open`-context-manager directly or returning a context manager that does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html) for contextlib suggests the following for handling optional contexts:

```
def process_file(filename):
    if filename is not None:
        cm = open(filename)
    else:
        cm = nullcontext()

    with cm as file:  # file will be None if no filename
        my_function(...., file)
```