# Extract data lines from txt for each ID if number of lines for each varies

Tags: python, txt

Suppose I have data in txt format structed as this:

```
|-------------------------|
| ID 1                    |
| Category A              |
| Class ABC               |
| Type 1                  |
| Subcat A                |
| positional entry 1      |
| positional entry 2      |
|-------------------------|
| ID 2                    |
| Category B              |
| Class ABC               |
| Type 2                  |
| Subcat B                |
| positional entry 1      |
| positional entry 2      |
| positional entry 3      |
|-------------------------|
| ID 3                    |
| Category A              |
| Class E                 |
| Type 4                  |
| Subcat A                |
| positional entry 1      |
|-------------------------|
```

The data is stored in one large txt file (approx. 7 GB) with more than 100 million rows. I want to extract only those IDs that fall into  Category A and Subcat A. However, I also want the positional entries. These are not fixed, it is unknown how many lines there are. So for each ID it can vary.

I tried to go through it with opening it as txt file and going through each line. My problem here is that each time the file pointer enters a new line the information so to say is lost, although I could try to set flags that are retained.

Second approach was to extract the beginning and end of each ID in a list first. Then check the position where an ID starts that has category A and Subcat A. However, I have many rows, so storing these information in ranges with lists that have so many elements is not possible. I wanted to check then for each ID to which range it falls.

Expected output:

```
|-------------------------|
| ID 1                    |
| Category A              |
| Class ABC               |
| Type 1                  |
| Subcat A                |
| positional entry 1      |
| positional entry 2      |
|-------------------------|
| ID 3                    |
| Category A              |
| Class E                 |
| Type 4                  |
| Subcat A                |
| positional entry 1      |
|-------------------------|
```

How can I do this extraction?

Edit:
positional entry 1,2 and so on just means this can be some varying entries. So these are lines with for example text entries which I need for later analysis.

Edit 2 according to Zach Young's answer:

When I adopt the code to the following:

```
import csv
DIVIDER = "-------------------------"

f_in = open(r"C:\myfile\testfile.txt")
block: list[str] = []

with open(r"C:\myfile\output.csv", "w", newline="") as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)
    for line in f_in:
        line = line.replace("|", "").strip()
        if line == DIVIDER:
            if len(block) > 4 and block[1] == "Category A" and block[4] == "Subcat A":
                print("check")
                print(block)
                writer.writerow(block)

            block = []
            continue

        block.append(line)
```

Then I get the ouptut as in the answer below, however I do not want transposing, I would like to have the expected output as I wrote it here.

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: I do not have working code.

Comment: If you add the code which you have tried it will be easier for you to get a working solution.

Comment: If you had working code you wouldn't be here :)  What about the code that 'loses the information each time the file pointer enters a new line' ?  can you also provide an example with the actual positional entries, not placeholders,  what exactly do they look like?

Comment: Well I used with open(...). Then I looped through each line of this file with for line in fname. However each iteration the loop begins again and I could store it over one iteration, but here in this case I would need to store information over several iterations.

Comment: Regarding the positional entries: Well this can be text or so. These are lines that contain information which I will need later on. But they highly vary.

Comment: Hi. Does the file have the vertical and horizontal lines, or did you add those for clarity? And please edit your question to include the code you’ve tried.

Comment: All lines are as I draw them, so the file does have these lines. As I said I have no code.

Comment: use `next()` to read multiple rows per iteration

Answer (score 2):

Below example should be self contained. Replace StringIO with files (see [How can I open multiple files using "with open" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617034/how-can-i-open-multiple-files-using-with-open-in-python)) and you can filter your data.

```
s = """
|-------------------------|
| ID 1                    |
| Category A              |
| Class ABC               |
| Type 1                  |
| Subcat B                |
| positional entry 1      |
| positional entry 2      |
|-------------------------|
| ID 2                    |
| Category B              |
| Class ABC               |
| Type 2                  |
| Subcat B                |
| positional entry 1      |
| positional entry 2      |
| positional entry 3      |
|-------------------------|
| ID 3                    |
| Category A              |
| Class E                 |
| Type 4                  |
| Subcat A                |
| positional entry 1      |
|-------------------------|
| ID 4                    |
| Category A              |
| Class Foo               |
| Type 999999             |
| Subcat A                |
| positional entry 1      |
| positional entry 2      |
| positional entry 3      |
| positional entry 4      |
| positional entry 5      |
| positional entry 6      |
|-------------------------|
"""

import re
import io
f=io.StringIO(s) # your data file
selected=io.StringIO() # filtered data

def take(data): # returns True if block selected
    c1=c2=False
    for s in data:
        if s.startswith('| Category A'): c1=True
        if s.startswith('| Subcat A'): c2=True
    return c1 and c2

    
data=[]
sep1=sep2=''
for line in f:
    if re.match('[|]-*[|]', line): # data record separator?
        sep1,sep2 = sep2,line
        if not data: continue # we are at data block begin
        if take(data):
            print('take')
            if selected.tell() == 0: # write separator before first selected record
                selected.write(sep1)
            selected.write(''.join(data))
            selected.write(sep2)
        else:
            print('toss')
        data=[]
        continue # separator not added to data
    data.append(line) # line is data line 
         

selected.seek(0)
print(selected.read())
```

Comment: Thanks for your post and +1, but I added a with open (r'C:\myfile.txt') as f before the for line in f and it does not work. It just prints toss. Could you make it a working example? I have one txt file which I need to open and extract from.

Comment: Add print(''.join(data)) in take function to see what it gets, pay attention to tabs and spaces. In main loop you may add if f.tell() > 1000: break to avoid scanning entire file.

Answer (score 1):

I see this problem as:

1. accumulate lines of a complete block
2. evaluate the complete block, and then conditionally print the block

...and, printing dividers at beginning and end of file, and between printed blocks.

I've created two files from the unmodified samples you shared. Both have no extraneous whitespace at the beginning; both have a final linebreak (an "empty line" at the bottom):

- input.txt:

  ```
  |-------------------------|
  | ID 1                    |
  | Category A              |
  | Class ABC               |
  | Type 1                  |
  | Subcat A                |
  | positional entry 1      |
  | positional entry 2      |
  |-------------------------|
  | ID 2                    |
  | Category B              |
  | Class ABC               |
  | Type 2                  |
  | Subcat B                |
  | positional entry 1      |
  | positional entry 2      |
  | positional entry 3      |
  |-------------------------|
  | ID 3                    |
  | Category A              |
  | Class E                 |
  | Type 4                  |
  | Subcat A                |
  | positional entry 1      |
  |-------------------------|
  ```
- target.txt:

  ```
  |-------------------------|
  | ID 1                    |
  | Category A              |
  | Class ABC               |
  | Type 1                  |
  | Subcat A                |
  | positional entry 1      |
  | positional entry 2      |
  |-------------------------|
  | ID 3                    |
  | Category A              |
  | Class E                 |
  | Type 4                  |
  | Subcat A                |
  | positional entry 1      |
  |-------------------------|
  ```

To start off, I want to see what capturing and printing every block looks like. Consider this simple program that just reads a block, and prints a block, but only after a complete block has been read:

```py
f = open("input.txt")

print(next(f), end="")          # print first line (assumed to be divider)

block: list[str] = []           # create empty list to accumulate lines of a block

for line in f:
    if line.startswith("|--"):  # look for block's terminating divider
        for x in block:         # print the accumulated lines of the block
            print(x, end="")
        print(line, end="")     # print terminal divider

        block = []              # reset block
        continue                # skip to next line

    block.append(line)          # otherwise, accumulate line in block
```

I expect to get out exactly what I put in. I test that:

```
% python3 main1.py > output.txt
% diff input.txt output.txt
```

diff doesn't complain, so I've got at least that much correct.

Next, I'll add in the evaluation step:

```py
f = open("input.txt")
print(next(f), end="")
block: list[str] = []

for line in f:
    if line.startswith("|--"):
        if len(block) > 4 and "Category A" in block[1] and "Subcat A" in block[4]:
            for x in block:
                print(x, end="")
            print(line, end="")

        block = []
        continue

    block.append(line)
```

I expect to get an output that matches target.txt. I test that:

```
% python3 main2.py > output.txt
% diff target.txt output.txt
```

Please, recreate the conditions for those tests exactly and try those two sample programs, without any modifications... not even the to the input path.

That will mean making sure the programs can access a file named input.txt. A straightforward way to do that would be to:

1. put the scripts and input.txt in the same directory
2. `cd` to that directory
3. run the scripts with a redirect (">") to an output file, like `Z:\your\path\to\python3 main1.py > output.txt`, and the same for `main2.py`

Do not change anything/add variables to the test, yet.

Once you've verified the second script exactly produces target.txt, you can move on to trying your input text.

Because of the size of your file, to start, I recommend adding a simple counter and then halting after the program has read enough blocks that should qualify; after, say... 100 blocks?:

```py
i = 0
for line in f:
    if line.startswith("|--"):
        i += 1
        ...
        block = []
        if i == 100:
            break
        continue
    ...
```

After that, maybe add in a file to write to, to avoid the prints and redirect. You don't need to do `with open(...)` for these programs: once the program finishes (even from an unhandled exeception), Python will close all open files.

Comment: Thanks for your post and +1, however it does not work. I replaced f = open("input.txt") with my file, so f= open(r'C:\myfile.txt') and I set f_in to f, so f_in = f. When I run it an empty output file is created.